# css piece de resistance

Tags: css, hover

i've been wrestling it out all week with a challenging design and im on my last piece de resistance and a hour left of the day,

I have a diamond/honeycomb ui here

http://jsfiddle.net/z42wg/25/

```
.diamonds li {
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    -moz-perspective: 1000;
    -ms-perspective: 1000;
    perspective: 1000;
    -ms-transform: perspective(1000px);
    -moz-transform: perspective(1000px);
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.diamond:hover .back,.diamond.hover .back {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
.diamond:hover .frontFlip,.diamond.hover .frontFlip {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flipper {
    -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transition: 0.6s;
    -moz-transition: 0.6s;
    -moz-transform: perspective(1000px);
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;
}
.frontFlip, .back {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transition: 0.6s;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transition: 0.6s;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transition: 0.6s;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.frontFlip {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    z-index: 2;
}
.back {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
.frontFlip .name {
    font-size: 2em;
    display: inline-block;
    background: rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.9);
    color: #f8f8f8;
    font-family: Courier;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    bottom: 60px;
    left: 25%;
    position: absolute;
    text-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em 0.05em #333;
    display: none;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-20deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-20deg);
    transform: rotate(-20deg);
}
```

currently on hovering the diamond the inner text uses a css3 transition to flip but the transition needs to be on the grey diamond its self

any pointers on where to move the css rules highly appreciated!!

Comment: I'm sure you've already seen this link and are basing your design off of it: http://cssdeck.com/labs/b1nfiuqm.  However, I noticed that it looks like you don't have your front and back inside the same "flipper" `div` as they do there which might be causing a problem.

Comment: it was inspired by this - http://davidwalsh.name/css-flip

yep i see what you mean there are two flippers in there but it's updated and still the same

http://jsfiddle.net/z42wg/31/

I believe its an issue were the css3 transform selector is sitting on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the appearance of flipping to be on the 'diamond'. You can move the remove the box-shadow on `.diamond li` and the background on `.diamonds .diamond` and put them on the `.diamond .content`

```
/* line 118, ../sass/screen.scss */
.diamonds .content {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 190px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 190px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(204,204,204);
  background: #f4f4f4;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/z42wg/44/

Comment: ha ah thanks for that!!

got it looking how i wanted now

http://fiddle.jshell.net/z42wg/58/